# Safari CSS flex box items going outside containing

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, flexbox

EDIT: Code below is not the most readable due to being constructed with php. I have included a codepen with sample data and more readable HTML to more clearly demonstrate the problem, that can be found: codepen.io/anon/pen/PbeGya here.

I am attempting to create a flexbox header for a website I am working on. I have gotten it to the point where it works beautifully in chrome and firefox, however when I view it in safari the elements drop to the bottom of their containing div and are outside of the background of the header.

I have enclosed the following screenshots to show the problem:

Here is how it is supposed to look and how it does look on chrome and firefox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grUCb.png)

And here is how it behaves on safari:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3v62.png)

Here is the relevant code as near as I can tell. Keep in mind that I am not a css expert by any means, and I have messed around with the code a lot in the last few hours trying to figure out whats going on.

```
<div id="uberbar">
<div class="menu-centering">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__row">
            <div class="grid_row">
                <a href="/" id="logopic">
                    <img src="redacted">
                </a>
                <a href="/" id="logopic-scroll">
                    <img src="redacted">
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $html_construction = "";
            $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Test');
            foreach ($array_menu as $array_item) {
                if( $array_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
                    $html_construction .= ("<div class='grid__item'> <a href='" . $array_item->url . "'>" . $array_item->title . "</a>");
                    if( is_null(get_nav_menu_item_children($array_item->ID, $array_menu)) == false ) {
                        $children_array = get_nav_menu_item_children($array_item->ID, $array_menu);
                        $html_construction .= "<div class='dropdown-content'>";
                        foreach ($children_array as $child) {
                            $html_construction .= ("<a href='" . $child->url . "'>" . $child->title . "</a>");
                        };
                        $html_construction .= "</div></div>";
                    } else {
                        $html_construction .= "</div>";
                    };
                };
            };
            echo $html_construction;
            ?>
            <div class="grid__item demo-menu"><a href="#bottom">Free Demo</a></div>                     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#uberbar  { 
  background:#505050; 
  padding:10px 0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  z-index:2000; 
  width:100%;
  height: 5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menu-centering {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#uberbar a {
  color:white;

    }
  #logopic {
    margin-right: 15em;
  }

  #logopic-scroll {
    display:none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15em;
  }

  .grid {
}

.grid__row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid__item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 12px;
  max-width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1; 

}

.grid__item:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


@media all and ( min-width: 480px ) {

  .grid__row--sm {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

}

@media all and ( min-width: 720px ) {

  .grid__row--md {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

}

@media all and ( min-width: 960px ) {

  .grid__row--lg {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

}


.demo-menu {
  background-color: #27a8df;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  }

.demo-menu-small {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #27a8df;
}

#uberbar .demo-menu-small a {
  color: #27a8df;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    background-color: #505050;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 200px;

}

  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #898989;
}

_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {

.grid__row {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
} 

}
.mobile-header-solution {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
  #uberbar {
    display:none;
  }
  .mobile-header-solution {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width : 1300px) {
  #logopic, #logopic-scroll { 
    margin-right: 10em;
    margin-left: 3em;
  }

  #logopic-scroll {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }

  .grid__item {
    max-width: 12%;
  }
}
```

Please point me in the right direction, I've now spent several hours looking at safari specific CSS bugs especially related to flexboxes and I can't seem to find anything that I think is likely to be the cause.

Comment: This markup seems really redundant and I find it hard to follow (there's a grid_row inside a grid__row???), and your code snippet doesn't render. It'd be nice if you could put this in a codepen or a jsfiddle to help out.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbeGya

Here is a codepen with the basic style. As you can see when it opens up in safari the behavior I am referring to. I also replaced the php specific html rendering with just plain jane html with sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use flexbox, use flexbox. This whole top: 50% translate(Y):-50% is trying to do vertical centering that flexbox can do.

Remove that from your .menu-centering, and give .menu-centering the following:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
```

And then give the containing .grid width:100%;

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Also, for the record, I mentioned that I am not a css expert, so there really is no reason to be as rude as you are being to me. But thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry you felt I'm being rude. In my mind, I'm just being succinct.

Read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and find a naming convention like SMACSS or BEM. Those things will help you immensely.

Comment: That was good advice to go all in on Flexbox, or not all.  I had some padding that made my items go outside the my display:flex container, really what I was trying to accomplish with the padding was easy with justify-content: space-around 